# XMLHttpRequest & FormData not submitting data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am trying to submit a form via ajax using the `post` method and a `FormData` object.

Here is a simplified version of the JavaScript:

```
var form=…; //  form element
var url=…;  //  action
form['update'].onclick=function(event) {    //  button name="update"
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post',url,true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var formData=new FormData(form);
        formData.append('update', true);    // makes no difference
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onload=function() {
        alert(this.response);
    };
};
```

The form has:

- a button (`type="button" name="update"`) to run the script
- no `action` and `method="get"`

My PHP script has the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
}

//  more stuff

print 'other stuff';
```

When I try it, the PHP falls through to the rest of the code, and I get the other output, rather than what I expect from the `print_r` statement.

I have tried the following variations:

- `new FormData()` (without the form). This *does* work if I add the `update` data manually.
- `new FormData(form)`. This does not work, whether I add the `update` manually or not.
- changing the form method to `post`.
- Firefox, Safari & Chrome on MacOS; all current versions.

The from itself looks something like this:

```
<form id="edit" method="post" action="">
    <p><label for="edit-summary">Summary</label><input id="edit-summary" name="summary" type="text"></p>
    <p><label for="edit-description">Description</label><input id="edit-description" name="description" type="text"></p>
    <p><label for="edit-ref">Reference</label><input id="edit-ref" name="ref" type="text"></p>
    <p><label for="edit-location">Location</label><input id="edit-location" name="location" type="text"></p>
    <p><button type="button" name="update">OK</button></p>
</form>
```

What should I do to submit the get this to work?

No jQuery, please.

Comment: What does your form HTML look like?

Comment: @E.Sundin See edited version of the question …

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The content type when sending a FormData object is multipart/form-data not url encoded.
Further more the proper boundary must be set for the request, which the user is unable to do. For this XMLHttpRequest sets the correct content type with the required boundary.
So all you have to do is not set the content type and it'll work.

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post',url,true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");<--don't do this
var formData=new FormData(form);
formData.append('update', true);    // makes no difference
xhr.send(formData);
xhr.onload=function() {
    alert(this.response);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Removing that line certainly got it working. To be honest, I don’t remember where I got that line in the first place.

Comment: Just for posterity, I think that `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` is to be used when sending POST data which is _not_ from a `FormData` object.

Comment: @Manngo Is there some spec-related source that states "when sending FormData over XMLHttpRequest, use `multipart/form-data`"? (sounds quite obvious worded that way, but still)

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the button to something other than "update" (and change it in your `form['update'].onclick...` as well). I think its clashing with the value you are trying to set on the FormData to trigger the PHP code.