# don't get my data with XMLHttpRequest POST across

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am fighting with getting my data from an html form into mySQL for 2 days, now...

While I solved maaany issues I am stuck with a (imho) empty `FormData` object. I have a form

```html
<form id="pricing">   
   ...
   <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" value=""/>
   ...
   <input type="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

The data shall be transmitted without redirecting to a new page, so I chose XMLHttpRequest, supporting also outdated browsers. The code is more or less copy paste from a tutorial.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#pricing');
  // listen for submit even
  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        // disable default action
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // configure a request
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'forms/pricing.php');
    
        // prepare form data
        let data = new FormData(form);
    
        // set headers
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    
        // send request
        xhr.send(data);
        console.log(data);
    
        // listen for `load` event
        xhr.onload = () => {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
  });
```

The landing page `forms/pricing.php` is reached, it successfully stores some fixed values (entered for debugging) into the database upon clicking "go". However, the `$_POST` var seems to be empty, my data object being stored via PDO

```js
        'fromDate' => isset($_POST["fromDate"]) ? $_POST["fromDate"] : '1',
```

stores `'1'` and not the `$_POST["fromDate"]`. And also in the console output of `console.log(data);` (where data is the FormData for POST, as seen in the 2nd snippet) I cannot find any of my data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest & FormData not submitting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156413/xmlhttprequest-formdata-not-submitting-data) . You have set the wrong content-type, acccording to the answer there. Let XHR take care of it for you.

Comment: so simple as that... Yes, that made the difference, thanks!